# Suppose $H, K\lhd G$. Show that there exists a 1-1 homomorphism $\phi:G/(H\cap K)\rightarrow G/H \times G/K.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-homomorphism

Suppose $H$ and $K$ are normal subgroups of a group $G$. Show that there exists a 1-1 homomorphism $\phi:G/(H\cap K)\rightarrow G/H \times G/K$.

Here are my thoughts:

If we can show that $\ker\phi=1$ then we have that $\phi$ is 1-1. So that's what I'm trying to do.

$G/H\cap K=\{gH\mid g\in K\}$

$G/H\times G/K=\{(gH,gK)\mid g\in G\}$

Then I considered the mapping where $\phi(gH)=(gH,gK)$ and looked at the kernel.

$\ker\phi$
$$=\{g\in G\mid (gH, gK)=(H,K)\}$$
$$=\{g\in G\mid g\in H\text{ and }g\in K\}$$
$$=H\cap K.$$

However, now I'm stuck. I'm not sure how to show that the intersection is just the identity. Am I on the right track? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: No you are not. To begin with:$$G/H\cap K\ne\{gH\mid g\in K\},$$$$G/H\times G/K\ne\{(gH,gK)\mid g\in G\},$$and your $\phi$ is ill-defined.

Comment: Hint: use the obvious map from $G$, then invoke the first isomorphism theorem.

Comment: There are several questions that look similar, but they have a different mapping most have the given assumption that the the intersection between $H$ and $K$ defined to be the identity. Also thank you for letting me know that that I have defined a few items incorrectly, but would you mind sharing what the correct way of defining them might be?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin by obvious map, are you talking about the natural projection?

Comment: This duplicate  answers your question: [Natural isomorphism $G/(H\cap K)\to G/H\times G/K$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109698) (found [using Approach$0$](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24G%2F(H%5Ccap%20K)%5Crightarrow%20G%2FH%20%5Ctimes%20G%2FK%24&p=1)) but take the time to review the definitions of a quotient group and of a direct product.

Comment: Thanks, I'll see if I can gather insight from their strategy. Although I do think it's relevant to note that I'm looking at $G/H\cap K$ not $G/(H\cap K)$, which to my understanding have their differences.

Comment: $(G/H)\cap K$ is nonsense, as you cannot intersect a subgroup of $G$ and a quotient of $G$. If you think that's what you are "looking at", then you have misunderstood the problem from the start.